# Simulating a simple test bench with a synthesized ROM core

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I'm completely new to the world of FPGA's and thought I'd start with a very simple project: a 4-bit 7-segment decoder. The first version I wrote purely in VHDL (it's basically a single combinatorial `select`, no clocks necessary) and it seems to work, but I'd also like to experiment with the "IP Cores" stuff in the Xilinx ISE.

So for now I'm using the "ISE Project Explorer" GUI, and I created a new project with a ROM core. The generated VHDL code is:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
-- synthesis translate_off
LIBRARY XilinxCoreLib;
-- synthesis translate_on
ENTITY SSROM IS
  PORT (
    clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
    addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END SSROM;

ARCHITECTURE SSROM_a OF SSROM IS
-- synthesis translate_off
COMPONENT wrapped_SSROM
  PORT (
    clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
    addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT;

-- Configuration specification
  FOR ALL : wrapped_SSROM USE ENTITY XilinxCoreLib.blk_mem_gen_v7_2(behavioral)
    GENERIC MAP (
      c_addra_width => 4,
      c_addrb_width => 4,
      c_algorithm => 1,
      c_axi_id_width => 4,
      c_axi_slave_type => 0,
      c_axi_type => 1,
      c_byte_size => 9,
      c_common_clk => 0,
      c_default_data => "0",
      c_disable_warn_bhv_coll => 0,
      c_disable_warn_bhv_range => 0,
      c_enable_32bit_address => 0,
      c_family => "spartan3",
      c_has_axi_id => 0,
      c_has_ena => 0,
      c_has_enb => 0,
      c_has_injecterr => 0,
      c_has_mem_output_regs_a => 0,
      c_has_mem_output_regs_b => 0,
      c_has_mux_output_regs_a => 0,
      c_has_mux_output_regs_b => 0,
      c_has_regcea => 0,
      c_has_regceb => 0,
      c_has_rsta => 0,
      c_has_rstb => 0,
      c_has_softecc_input_regs_a => 0,
      c_has_softecc_output_regs_b => 0,
      c_init_file_name => "SSROM.mif",
      c_inita_val => "0",
      c_initb_val => "0",
      c_interface_type => 0,
      c_load_init_file => 1,
      c_mem_type => 3,
      c_mux_pipeline_stages => 0,
      c_prim_type => 1,
      c_read_depth_a => 16,
      c_read_depth_b => 16,
      c_read_width_a => 7,
      c_read_width_b => 7,
      c_rst_priority_a => "CE",
      c_rst_priority_b => "CE",
      c_rst_type => "SYNC",
      c_rstram_a => 0,
      c_rstram_b => 0,
      c_sim_collision_check => "ALL",
      c_use_byte_wea => 0,
      c_use_byte_web => 0,
      c_use_default_data => 0,
      c_use_ecc => 0,
      c_use_softecc => 0,
      c_wea_width => 1,
      c_web_width => 1,
      c_write_depth_a => 16,
      c_write_depth_b => 16,
      c_write_mode_a => "WRITE_FIRST",
      c_write_mode_b => "WRITE_FIRST",
      c_write_width_a => 7,
      c_write_width_b => 7,
      c_xdevicefamily => "spartan3e"
    );
-- synthesis translate_on
BEGIN
-- synthesis translate_off
U0 : wrapped_SSROM
  PORT MAP (
    clka => clka,
    addra => addra,
    douta => douta
  );
-- synthesis translate_on

END SSROM_a;
```

It's initialized with these contents:

```
memory_initialization_radix=2;
memory_initialization_vector=
0000001,
1001111,
0010010,
0000110,
1001100,
0100100,
0100000,
0001111,
0000000,
0000100,
0001000,
1100000,
0110001,
1000010,
0110000,
0111000,
```

It has three pins: `clka`, `addra` and `douta`. 
I've also generated a test bench with the GUI, then edited it slightly so that it changes the input after 100 ns:

```
   uut: SSROM PORT MAP (
          clka => clk,
          addra => addra,
          douta => douta
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clka_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

      addra <= "0101";
      wait for 100 ns;

      wait;
   end process;
```

But when I run the simulation, the value of the `douta` signal is always undefined:

[image: Simulation result]

What gives?

Comment: We need the SSROM code to help you.

Comment: Which file is that? The `.xco`?

Comment: The .v or .vhd. .xco isn't human readable.

Comment: OK I edited the question by inserting the `.vhd` file generated for the ROM core.

Comment: Are you sure that you compiled the library for your simulator? If I remember correctly, Xilinx provides a cli tool 'xcomp' for that. Check whether your ROM is unbound in the simulator output, after all, coregen simply delivers a set of parameters for a library, not an actual core which can be simulated...

Comment: @BennyBarns: I'm running the simulation from the ISE Navigator by double-clicking on `Simulate Behaviour Model`. Like I said, I'm a total newbie here; could you expand on how I should run the simulation?

Comment: In that case, no; the xilinx tools should know about the xilinx libraries. Do you get any messages about an entity being 'unbound'?

Comment: The code you have posted looks like it should work, though I can't test it for you as I rarely use Xilinx (IMO Xilinx tools are bad, I avoid them).   It is much better and more portable to infer a ROM, rather than use a macro.  Just define an array of std_logic_vectors to be a constant. (i.e. a two dimensional array of bits)  That will suggest a ROM to any decent synthesis and simulation tool.

Comment: There is a technique on Xilinx FPGAs called "ROM Initialization" which can be used to pre-initialize a piece of memory. Building the memory itself can be done using `BRAM_TDP_MACRO` or by inferring it. See Language Templates in Xilinx ISE and the XST guide for your specific part. Simulating these should be easy and ports directly into an FPGA without issues. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: For me it looks like you have a SRAM rather than ROM, are you sure you generated the right memory type?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the signals inside the SSROM module using the simulation tool.  Sometimes looking at the inputs inside the instantiated can help illuminate where the problem is located.  Maybe a signal you thought was connected actually is not.

Another thing to investigate is your .mif file.  Xilinx uses a .mif file in simulations to initialize the memory contents for simulation.  If you've inadvertently moved or deleted the .mif file, you'll see results like this.